# How do I increase the size of an Azure File Storage CloudFile before I know the file size?

Tags: stream, zip, cloud, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm using Azure File Storage to store some files, and I want to create a zip file containing some of these files on the same Azure file share.

This is my code so far:

```
private void CreateZip(CloudFileDirectory directory) {

    if (directory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(directory));

    var zipFilename = $"{directory.Name}.zip";

    var zip = directory.GetFileReference(zipFilename);
    if (!zip.Exists()) { 

        zip.Create(0);  // <-- I don't know what size its gonna be!!

        using (var zipStream = zip.OpenWrite(null))
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create)) {

            foreach (var file in directory.ListFilesAndDirectories().OfType<CloudFile>()) {
                if (file.Name.Equals(zipFilename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    continue;                        

                using (var fileStream = file.OpenRead()) {

                    var entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                        fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream); // <-- exception is thrown
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line `zip.Create(0);` this creates an empty file. I then go on to use this file reference to create a zip file, and add stuff to it, but when it gets to the `fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);` it throws an exception with this message:

```
The remote server returned an error: (416) The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.
```

Presumably because the file size is 0 and it's unable to automatically increase the size.

I can create the file with `int.MaxValue`, but then I get a 2GB file. I can't even work out the size of the file I'm adding to the achive and resize the file to extend it by that amount, because its a zip and its gonna compress and change the file size.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is more related with System.IO.Compression. I have rewrite your code, please use memory stream instead like the following code. It works fine on my side. Hope it could give you some tips.

```html
       public static void CreateZip(CloudFileDirectory directory)
        {

            if (directory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(directory));

            var zipFilename = $"{directory.Name}.zip";          
            var zip = directory.GetFileReference(zipFilename);
            if (!zip.Exists())
            {

                //zip.Create(600000);  // <-- I don't know what size its gonna be!!

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {

                        foreach (var file in directory.ListFilesAndDirectories().OfType<CloudFile>())
                        {
                            if (file.Name.Equals(zipFilename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                continue;

                            using (var fileStream = file.OpenRead())
                            {

                                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                                {

                                    fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream); // <-- exception is thrown
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    zip.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I actually tried using a memory stream, but couldn't get it to work, and looking at your code I think it was because I forgot to reset the postition of the stream back to 0... thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible (how?) to start the `UploadFromStream` in the beginning, so that we continuously upload the stream while we write the files in the `foreach` to it? I'm stuck trying to figure this out!